# Sorting arrays within a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

The information inside the arrays is in the "reverse" order of how I want it. Ideally it could be sorted by the dates within the array but I'm 100% certain just reversing the order would work. 
By using something like this:

```
sorted(Dictionary[self], key=lambda i: i[1][0], reverse=True)
```

I know that the above JUST sorts the arrays themselves into reverse order and not the data inside the array into reverse order. 
With the Dictionary like this (all items are a file name)

```
Dictionary = {'a':[XPJulianDay(Timefurthestinpastfromnow), ... XPJulianDay(timeclosest2currnttime)], 'b':[RQJulianDay(Timefurthestinpastfromnow), ... RQJulianDay(timeclosest2currnttime)], 'c':[WSJulianDay(Timefurthestinpastfromnow), ... WSJulianDay(timeclosest2currnttime)] ..... (9 different ones total) }
```

turning into this

```
Dictionary = {'a':[XPJulianDay(timeclosest2currnttime), ... XPJulianDay(Timefurthestinpastfromnow)], 'b':[RQJulianDay(timeclosest2currnttime), ... RQJulianDay(Timefurthestinpastfromnow)], 'c':[WSJulianDay(timeclosest2currnttime), ... WSJulianDay(Timefurthestinpastfromnow)] .... }
```

Comment: Please write complete example of `Dictionary`, before and after the needed transformation.

Comment: @jmd_dk is that acceptable?

Comment: I guess it's good enough for valid answers to be written, but really you should write code that we can copy, paste and run. Currently, `file1` etc. are not defined. We don't even know what kind of objects they are...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try that:

```
Dictionary.update({ k: sorted(v) for k, v in Dictionary.items() })
```

It updates the dictionary with its own keys, with sorted values.

Example:

```
>>> Dictionary = {"a": [7,6,1,2], "b": [8,0,2,5] }
>>> Dictionary.update({ k: sorted(v) for k, v in Dictionary.items() })
>>> Dictionary
{'a': [1, 2, 6, 7], 'b': [0, 2, 5, 8]}
>>>
```

Note that a new dictionary is created for the call to `.update()` using a dict comprehension.

If needed you can replace `sorted()` by `reversed()` ; but `reversed()` returns an iterator so if you want a list you need to call it with `list()` (it is better to keep the iterator if you can).

Example with `reversed`:

```
>>> Dictionary = {"a": [7,6,1,2], "b": [8,0,2,5] } ; Dictionary.update({ k: reversed(v) for k, v in Dictionary.items() })
>>> Dictionary
{'a': <list_reverseiterator object at 0x7f537a0b3a10>, 'b': <list_reverseiterator object at 0x7f537a0b39d0>}
>>>
```

Comment: This may work for me. That is a LOT of changing within my current code potentially. Let me save a copy before I go down the rabbit hole I'll let you know. It looks like a good answer. Thank you for the reply.

Comment: Ok @Pandasncode ; if you don't need to keep references to `Dictionary` you can simply reassign it (doing `Dictionary = { ... }` instead of `update({ ... })`, it will be more efficient if the dictionary is big

Comment: "too many values to unpack" Guess mine is too large to do it that way.

Comment: no no it has nothing to do with data too large - update your question otherwise I can't help. When doing k, v = dictionary.items() this means "unpacking", i.e assigning something with multiple values to multiple variables (for example). What does `.items()` return ? Should be a key, value pair in an iterator

Comment: Okay. I'm going to try to update it in a manner that can be understood for how many "items" are in each list.

Comment: also printing the dictionary prints out all the items. All 9 arrays with all the names in the opposite order of what I want. The number of items in each list within the dictionary will be unknown and could be massive. There is not a definitive number.

Comment: Your question does not include all the elements to receive a definitive answer since there is no information/demonstrable code to understand what are the objects in your dictionary. However, with this answer you can see how to sort/reverse order of iterables stored in a dictionary. The error you have is from your code, not from the answer code. Without more details I cannot help more

Comment: it does what you have described and I accepted the answer. the issue was definitely with something I had typed as well. What if I wanted them to be ordered (7,6,5,4) ect? That was my goal. I just described it poorly I guess... So currently 20170582000 is ordered before 201858145.

Comment: combine `sorted()` and `reversed()` : `Dictionary.update({ k: reversed(sorted(v)) for k, v in Dictionary.items() })`

Comment: That as well as This: Dictionary.update({k : sorted(v, reverse=True) for k, v in Dictionary.items()}) yield the same error happening : #Create a list of datetime objects and a dict where the key is the dictionary and value is path. my print statements for both yield exactly what I wanted so thank you. I just have to work the rest of the code to update it now as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the dict comprehension as stated by @mguijarr or use `dict` and `zip`

```
Dictionary = dict(zip(Dictionary, map(sorted, Dictionary.values()))))
```

But if your keys really are just the `'a'`, `'b'`, `...` then why are you using a dict? Just use a list...

Comment: It's a dictionary of arrays of lists.